Using Chromaprint to align audio
The idea is to auto align recordings of the same event from different microphones/devices.
I found ChromaPrint but I 'm not sure how to use it for audio alignment. I'm getting the raw fingerprint with int  chromaprint_get_raw_fingerprint(ChromaprintContext *ctx, uint32_t **fingerprint, int *size); all right, for two files, for example.
There's a partial match all right,
std::vector<uint32_t> hashes; // fill these with chromaprint_hash_fingerprint
auto j = hashes[0] ^ hashes[1];
int Diff = 0;
while (j != 0)
{
    auto j2 = j & 1;
    Diff += j2;
    j >>= 1;
}
// diff - a close value to 32

So yes they are close all right, but how will this help me align the audio files?
Best.
